# How to Make an Android App Using Android Phone (without internet network)

Tags: android, html, apk

I wanted to create android app using my android phone. I have a good idea about HTML & CSS. Isn't it possible?

Comment: you mean without using PC or Laptop????

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/building-android-apps-with-aide-671149/

refer this link for more details

Comment: without pc & internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. No need to use pc/laptop. You need no internet connection. You should use Droidera. Droidera is an offline app maker for android users.
 This video is recommended for you.
 https://youtube.com/watch?v=NEAMVpZvXI0

It is a very useful tutorial. I think it will be helpful for you.